# Is there a limit on query time for an Oracle linked server?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2012, linked-server

We've created a stored procedure to pull in full copies of some Oracle tables with a Linked Server.

Over the course of 11 hours, the procedure correctly populated the first 11 tables but failed with this error on table 12:

```
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Refresh_From_Oracle, Line 45
The OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "ORACLE_LIVE" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Procedure Refresh_From_Oracle, Line 45
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "ORACLE_LIVE".
```

Is there anything there that gives a clue as to why the procedure failed when it got to table 12? Or is there a limit to how long a procedure can run, or a query can run against a linked server?

All tables except 12 and 13 have <2,000,000 rows, and 12 and 13 have about 70,000,000 each.

Here is the stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Jack Douglas
-- Create date: 2016-10-07
-- Description: Truncates and re-populates UAT copies of Oracle data
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Refresh_From_Oracle] 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.TABLE1;
    INSERT INTO dbo.TABLE1 SELECT * FROM ORACLE_LIVE..ORALIVE.TABLE1; 

    …

    TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.TABLE12;
    INSERT INTO dbo.TABLE12 SELECT * FROM ORACLE_LIVE..ORALIVE.TABLE12; 

    TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.TABLE13;
    INSERT INTO dbo.TABLE13 SELECT * FROM ORACLE_LIVE..ORALIVE.TABLE13; 

END
```

Comment: The configuration option `remote query timeout (s)` is exactly about that. Is it set to anything other than the default (2147483647)? BTW, looking at the error, it doesn't look like it has anything to do with this setting.

Comment: Does `remote query timeout` apply even after the remote query has begun returning data?

Comment: Timeout is controlled by the client, so it's quite possible that the time taken to fetch all the data is taken into account. However, I don't think it's the situation you are facing.

Comment: Thanks — I think I've discovered the problem and it's on the Oracle end.

Comment: Check for errors on the Oracle side

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be on the Oracle side:

```
Tue Oct 18 05:41:17 2016
ORA-01555 caused by SQL statement below (Query Duration=30945 sec, SCN: 0x0aee.4682f3e7):
Tue Oct 18 05:41:17 2016
```

It's the classic 'Snapshot too old' issue with a long-running transaction and MVCC.